# Can this dishwasher door be repaired?

Tags: doors, dishwasher

The bottom of our dishwasher door is damaged.  Can it be repaired and brought back to a newish state?  Or does the facade need to be replaced?

[image]

[image]

Comment: It can be repaired, but would check piece of new facade first, might be cheap.  Would need something like auto body filler, some sandpaper, and probably paint or stick on covering if wanting different look.  Depends on how much like new you want newest to look.